How to update a file path each week with different file names
I have two workbooks i use weekly.  Workbook 1 is scheduling and other info.  Workbook 2 is Pick ups.  WB2 gets info from WB1 and then closes WB1.  I like to see if there is a way to update a file path and workbook name each week using VBA. Each new WB1 will have a date that is on Sunday. MM.DD.YY.  WB1 will always be saved as SCHED MM.DD.YY. WB2 will always be Sched Pickup MM.DD.YY.
This is the current script that I use.  What I would like to see is if there is a way to change 11.17.24 to another date without having to go through and change it weekly.  I primary work in WB2 and this script is ran from there.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _"C:\Users\jvittur\OneDrive\Desktop\Orginal Schedules\SCHED 11.17.24.xlsm"
Windows("SCHED 11.17.24.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("ROADMAP").Select
Range("A400:AI550").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Sched Pickup 11.17.24.xlsm").Activate
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A5").Select
Windows("SCHED 11.17.24.xlsm").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False

I have been looking everywhere on the internet but haven't found anything.

Besides your question you may have a look onto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Where is the code located (in which workbook)? Based on which input shall the date code be generated? (e.g. date when the code is run, file name of one the workbooks, newest file in folder, user input, ...)

The code is stored and ran from WB2

This function creates the date of Sunday before or equal today date.
An example for the usage is in the test Sub.
Function strgen()

dat = Date - Weekday(Now(), 1) + 1
datstring = Month(dat) & "." & Day(dat) & "." & Right(Year(dat), 2)
strgen = datstring & ".xlsm"
End Function

Sub test()


Debug.Print strgen

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\jvittur\OneDrive\Desktop\Orginal Schedules\SCHED " & strgen

Windows("SCHED " & strgen).Activate

End Sub


This worked great until the following Sunday came.  The schedule is posted usually about 2 weeks in advance so for example.  Today is 11/18 and we will be working in WB2 (Sched Pickup 11.24.24  and a new Sched Pickup 12.1.24.  I am getting a run-time error "1004'.  couldn't find C:.....Swing weekly 12.1.24 when still working in 11.24.24 for data.  Sched Pickup 12.1.24 will be created later today or tomorrow.  How can i fix this issue.

Save Files with a Name on a Weekly Basis

You never mentioned the name of the destination worksheet (DST_SHEET_NAME). Handle this issue before running the code.
It will extract the date from the open file (destination workbook) and based on it and the corresponding constants, open the source file. It will add 7 days to the date and build the new file paths.
It will copy (maybe out-comment this line while testing) as suggested in your code and will show a message box with the old and new file paths.
Even if this is correct, carefully think it through what to do next i.e. before you decide to uncomment the out-commented code near the end i.e. the remaining open file will be the one with the new name i.e. it is not entirely clear which one you want to rename.

Sub SaveWeekly()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_FOLDER_PATH As String = _
        "C:\Users\jvittur\OneDrive\Desktop\Orginal Schedules\"
    Const SRC_FILE_NAME_LEFT As String = "SCHED "
    Const SRC_FILE_NAME_RIGHT As String = ".xlsm"
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Roadmap"
    Const SRC_RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "A400:AI550"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1" ' ???
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    Const MID_NAME_PATTERN As String = "mm.dd.yy"
    Const DATE_DAYS_DIFFERENCE As Long = 7
    
    ' Reference the destination objects.
    
    ' e.g. 'Sched Pickup 11.10.24.xlsm' but we don't care because we know
    ' that its base name ends with the date define by 'MID_NAME_PATTERN'.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' If you're going to run this code from a button on this sheet,
    ' and the sheet will always change, use 'Set dws = dwb.ActiveSheet'.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim dfcell As Range: Set dfcell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
    
    ' Build the old mid (date) name.
    Dim dOldName As String: dOldName = dwb.Name
    Dim dbLen As Long: dbLen = InStrRev(dOldName, ".") - 1
    Dim mLen As Long: mLen = Len(MID_NAME_PATTERN)
    Dim OldMidName As String: OldMidName = Mid(dOldName, dbLen - mLen + 1, mLen)
    
    ' Build the old source file path.
    Dim sOldFilePath As String: sOldFilePath = SRC_FOLDER_PATH _
        & SRC_FILE_NAME_LEFT & OldMidName & SRC_FILE_NAME_RIGHT
    If Len(Dir(sOldFilePath)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file """ & sOldFilePath & """ doesn't exist!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Reference the source objects.
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sOldFilePath)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(SRC_RANGE_ADDRESS)

    ' Copy
    srg.Copy Destination:=dfcell

    ' Retrieve the old year, month and day as strings.
    Dim yStr As String, mStr As String, dStr As String, n As Long
    For n = 1 To mLen
        Select Case Mid(MID_NAME_PATTERN, n, 1)
            Case "y": yStr = yStr & Mid(OldMidName, n, 1)
            Case "m": mStr = mStr & Mid(OldMidName, n, 1)
            Case "d": dStr = dStr & Mid(OldMidName, n, 1)
            Case Else ' it's a dot
        End Select
    Next n
    
    ' Build the new mid (date) name.
    Dim OldDate As Date:
    OldDate = DateSerial(CLng(yStr), CLng(mStr), CLng(dStr))
    Dim NewDate As Date: NewDate = OldDate + DATE_DAYS_DIFFERENCE
    Dim NewMidName As String: NewMidName = Format(NewDate, MID_NAME_PATTERN)
    
    ' Build the new file paths.
    Dim sNewFilePath As String:
    sNewFilePath = Replace(sOldFilePath, OldMidName, NewMidName)
    Dim dOldFilePath As String: dOldFilePath = dwb.FullName
    Dim dNewFilePath As String:
    dNewFilePath = Replace(dOldFilePath, OldMidName, NewMidName)
    
    ' Warning!!!
    MsgBox "Old Source: " & sOldFilePath & vbLf & "New Source: " _
        & sNewFilePath & vbLf & vbLf _
        & "Old Desti: " & dOldFilePath & vbLf & "New Desti: " _
        & dNewFilePath & vbLf & vbLf _
        & "If this is correct, decide what to do on your own!", vbCritical
    
'    ' Save the source file with the new name and close it.
'    swb.SaveAs sNewFilePath
'    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' just got saved
'
'    ' Save the destination file with the new name.
'    dwb.SaveAs dNewFilePath

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "New weekly files created.", vbInformation
End Sub


Select and Activate are not necessary in your script. Please read
How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA
Pls try
    
    Const SPATH = "C:\Users\jvittur\OneDrive\Desktop\Orginal Schedules\"
    Const SrcFILE = "SCHED $DATE$.xlsm"
    Const DestFILE = "Sched Pickup $DATE$.xlsm"
    Dim dDate As Date, sDate As String
    ' get the first day (Sunday) of this week, modify as need
    dDate = Date - Weekday(Date, 1) + 1
    ' format date string
    sDate = Format(dDate, "MM.dd.yy")
    ' open workbook
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=SPATH & Replace(SrcFILE, "$DATE$", sDate)
    ' copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ROADMAP").Range("A400:AI550").Copy Workbooks(Replace(DestFILE, "$DATE$", sDate)).Range("A5")
    
    

